# Is there an algorithm giving the shortest path visiting all nodes in a directed weighted graph?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, hamiltonian-path

I am looking for an algorithm mentioned in the title. The graph is complete, i.e. every two nodes have two edges in between with different directions.

I tried Traveling salesman method, but it gives a cycle path, however I don't need the path to return to the starting node. I also tried Hamilton path, but it mainly solves shortest path for undirected graph. Are there any methods to solve such issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Traveling sales problem with an additional node that has distance zero to every other node in the graph. Take the path and erase the edges tied to the new node and you have your path.

Answer (score 3):

The transformation (adding a dummy node with zero distance to and from every original node) described by @AnilCh in a comment works if you have a solver for the asymmetric traveling salesman problem (ATSP).  If not, there is an additional transformation from ATSP to TSP.  See
Kumar, R., and Li, H. (1994). “On Asymmetric TSP: Transformation to Symmetric TSP and Performance Bound.” [http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~rkumar/PUBS/atsp.pdf](http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/%7Erkumar/PUBS/atsp.pdf).

Comment: Hi! I used the google tools for traveling salesman problem (https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp). However it seems to be only for the symmetric problem. Thanks for the paper you provided. I will take a look!